# Get HTML element through other element by ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need get HTML element by ID in other element. But i need to do it through parent element.

```
<div id="one" class="a">html value 1
    <div id="two" class="a">html value 2</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Uh, what? Are you trying to get the `id` of `#one` by clicking on `#two`?

Comment: I need get element with ID TWO through element with ID ONE.

Comment: Why? If you know the id, you know the id and can just get the element by it. There is no need to involve another element in this.

Comment: For example like this: $(#one).betElementById("two") - but this does not work

Comment: In the project ID for perent element unique but ID for child is repeatable in the code. Thats why I need use way through parent element.

Comment: Maybe `.find` is what you are looking for `$("#one").find("#two");`. But id really should be unique.

Comment: ID should always be unique.. you cannot(shouldnot) have two elements with the same ID

Comment: @lugaru — The id is **not** repeatable. If the HTML repeats it, then the HTML is invalid. Fix the HTML, use a class instead, then you won't have this problem as you can use `getElementsByClassName` on an HTML Element Node.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#one div:first').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

ID should always be unique .. two html elements with the same id is invalid.. you can replace the ids with class and use class selector..

**HTML**

```
<div id="one" class="a">html value 1
  <div  class="a two">html value 2</div> 
  <div  class="a three">html value 3</div> 
  <div  class="a four">html value 4</div> 
    ....
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('#one.two').text(); //to get the text inside the element having class as two , gives(html value 2) here..
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
$('#one > div').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `$('#one #two')` should return the jquery-wrapped element `div#two`.
**Note**: `id` should be unique